# Is there an easy way for python Unittest to do unit test for only a portion of a function?

Tags: python, unit-testing

The to-be-tested python function contains continuous parts which are not well modulized, i.e.:

```
def f():
  do stuff A
  ...
  do stuff B
  ...
  do stuff C
```

If I just want to test stuff "B", and I don't want to manually mock up each single line in stuff "A/C", it there anyway for python unit test to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  Break it out into a separate function...where it should be anyway if you want to test it.

Comment: modify the code that you are going to test is an option?

Answer (score 4):

You need to refactor this function using method extraction. That will create a larger number of functions which can be unit tested.

```
def a():
  do stuff A

def b():
  do stuff B

def c():
  do stuff C

def f():
  a()
  b()
  c()
```

Comment: If the coder has written untestable code, then as a tester you should report that fact. Generally code like this has bugs so test it as best as you can and report some bugs as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot refactor the code, then try testing it using a fuzzer to generate random test data.